# Flutter How to use calendar used in ios or uses Hig

Tags: flutter, calendar

I am creating a calendar app with Flutter, but I notice that the calendar design uses HIG.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAT16.jpg)

I tried to use Sfcalendar Table-Calendar and all major packages, but I can reach my goal.
Is there any package that uses hig or iOS?

Or do I have to make my own package?

Comment: try use table_calendar you can achieve that design since table calendar is customizable

Comment: Thank you very much. If it is not too much trouble, I would like to know argument that you said.